# Can't Create/POST event in Office365 API through AngularJS - ADAL JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, azure, office365

I have used [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to create a calendar app (Read Write). I have registered app in https://manage.windowsazure.com/ and successfully able to add Oauth2 for login, reading calendar event.

But I can't do a POST request for event. It throws 400 error.

I did a post request [image]

And this is the result:

[image]

**I have done the Calendar.ReadWrite permission on AAD.**

[image]

What I may be missing here?

Comment: Permissions appear to be correct.  Can you please send us headers for request and response, for a repro?  The issue is related to supporting CORS for single page app such as yours.

Comment: Venkat, I have posted network headers info here. http://imgur.com/gallery/t4jbeiF/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. So the required date format for POST request was culprit. I had the "Start/End" data as simple date with "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss" format.

[image]

Because of this browser threw "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error rather giving the error information. I had to use FIDDLER to trace the request/responses.

All I had to do use convert this date string to ISO String (See the Start and End properties)
[image]